# Component not receiving props when pushed from same path - react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

This is the code that works ...for pushing to different routes

```
sendToMessage = (item)=>{
    let path = '/messages';
    this.props.history.push({
      pathname:path,
      state:{
        clientid:item.clientid,
        clientname:item.clientname
      }
    });
  }
```

So, when I click on the item from a different route it works perfectly and the component receives the props sent

But when I am on the /messages page already and click on the item, I am not receiving the props so I can update the page with the new data.
why is this happening?

I'd like it to work for all situations, 
whether from same route or from different route.

Now, I do receive this warning

```
Hash history cannot PUSH the same path; a new entry will not be added to the history stack
```

This is how I am trying to access the props in the destination component

```
 componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log('nextPRops : ',nextProps);

  }
```

but shouldnt I be able to still receive the props that I am sending??

is there any other way to send props to other component? these components are not parent and child component, so cant really pass props like that.

More details : it's a feature where a user gets a notification of message and gets taken to the messages page to that specific message he/she clicked on. Now, it may happen that the user is already on that page when the notification appears. in that case, we still need to show the new message when the user clicks on it. although it was made to bring to different route but it should also work when client is already on that page hope this makes it a little more clear

Comment: Are you using redux for this project, if so, then you can update clientid and clientname in redux and always access it from redux store, so instead of trying to route and send you can update the data in redux store and that will trigger your componentWillReceiveProps function

Comment: One more solution would also be to change the routing path, in case you have pathname like client - change the path to client/:clientid - if you use the routing in this way then you wont get this warning

Comment: why do you want to route to the same page

Comment: it's a feature where a user gets a notification of message and gets taken to the messages page to that specific message he/she clicked on.
 Now, it may happen that the user is already on that page when the notification appears. in that case, we still need to show the new message when the user clicks on it. 
although it was made to bring to different route but it should also work when client is already on that page
hope this makes it a little more clear

Comment: @Kowsalya , yeah that sounds like a good idea. and I may see if I can use react context here.

Comment: @faraz, thank you, I will post both of my comments in the answer section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1:**
You can use redux to store clientid and clientname in redux and always access it from redux store, so instead of trying to route, you can update the data in redux store and that will trigger your componentWillReceiveProps function

**Method 2:**
One more solution would be to change the routing path, in case you have pathname like client - change the path to client/:clientid - if you use the routing in this way then you wont get the warning when you try to route from same component to same component

Answer (score 0):

As what the warning said by `react-router`, you can't `push` to the same page.

Alternatively, you can/should use component's `state`, by updating the component state, it will rerender the component.

```
state = {
    clientid: '',
    clientname: ''
}

sendToMessage = (item) => {
    this.setState({
        clientid: item.clientid,
        clientname: item.clientname
    });
}
```

Comment: the data is being sent from a different component. so, it's the header where I am searching from and sending to different routes.
but a person may search and click from the same route too, so that's why I need this to work.

Comment: Can you add little more about the architecture of your project like this search and other different component in your question to get better understanding what you are trying to achieve

Comment: yes, it is easier to help if you can provide the component code